# Categories and child nodes drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-views

Hello i`m new to drupal and  i know maybe there are a lot of article talking about my problem but i did not find any straightforward answer..

i`m building a site using Drupal 6 and i created the followings : -

**i built two content types ( category , final_node ).**

**i created two pages via views module ( category , final_node ).**

**i built two terms for a taxonomy vocabulary (category and final node and assigned these two terms to their content types ).**

**i created block to retrieve all the nodes from (category content type).**

the problem is i dont know how to tell drupal when the users click on one of these nodes (categories) redirect him to (final_node page) and show him all the nodes that assigned to that category .

is there a way in views or i just need to build final_node page via hook_menu 
advice please .

thanks in advance .

Comment: why no body answering this .. !!

Comment: This is probably because it is not clear what you are asking. If you simply want a list of nodes which are assigned a taxonomy term you can use `taxonomy/term/<term id>`. If you are looking for something else please try to explain better.